# ESP8266 Skips some data from GET request over HTTPS

Tags: https, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Starting from the WiFiClient HTTPS Request example, I'm trying to get some code from a Github Gist using their API, but some parts of the file are missing

```
[...]

const char* host = "api.github.com";
const int httpsPort = 443;
String url = "/gists/0b3d5d67342c055cc9ba34b59d075da7";

// Use web browser to view and copy
// SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate
const char fingerprint[] PROGMEM = "59 74 61 88 13 CA 12 34 15 4D 11 0A C1 7F E6 67 07 69 42 F5";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    wifiSetup();

    // Use WiFiClientSecure class to create TLS connection
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

    Serial.printf("Using fingerprint '%s'\n", fingerprint);
    client.setFingerprint(fingerprint);

    if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
        Serial.println("Connection failed");
        return;
    }

    Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);

    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "User-Agent: ESP8266\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

    Serial.println("Request sent");
    while (client.connected()) {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        if (line == "\r") {
            Serial.println("Headers received");
            break;
        }
    }

    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    line = line.substring(line.indexOf("content\":") + 10, line.indexOf("},") - 2);

    Serial.println("Reply was:");
    Serial.println("==========");
    Serial.println(toHTML(line));
    Serial.println("==========");

    Serial.println("Setup end");
}

void loop() {

}


String toHTML(String source) {
    Serial.print("toHTML length before/after: ");
    Serial.print(source.length());
    Serial.print("/");
    source.replace("\\\\n", "==NEWLINE==");//Preserve document newlines
    source.replace("\\n", "\n");//Replace newline
    source.replace("==NEWLINE==", "\\n");
    source.replace("\\\"", "\"");//Replace quotes
    source.replace("\\t", "\t");//Replace tabs
    Serial.println(source.length());
    return source;
}
```

File I'm trying to get:

```
[...]
    function printDebugMap() {
        map.forEach((value, key) => {
            printDebug(`${key} = [${value}]`);
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="AppName">Spreadsheet Automatico</h1>

    <form onsubmit="return doNameInput()">
        <p>Nome giocatori:</p>
        <input type="text" id="nameBox">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <hr/>
```

What I actually get: some text is skipped

```
[...]
    function printDebugMap() {
        map.forEach((value, key) => {
            printDebug(`${ype="text" id="nameBox">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <hr/>
```

when I add some random unrelated code which part is missing part changes, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: It's possible the repeated use of String class calls is causing your Sketch to run out of memory. To see if you've received the correct response, I'd add a Serial.println(line); after each client.readStringUntil(). If the printed raw response is correct and the toHTML is incorrect, you'll know the problem is in the code after the client.readStringUntil() calls.  Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, the issue was memory fragmentation, the data in the stream was correct but the String didn't always append the data.
Here's the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59329485/12519963